# UBUNTU 17.04 freezes often

Tags: kernel

When it freezes  with several programs , then I can proceed after ~ 30 sec or more. The mouse can often be moved, keyboardstrokes can eventualt be remembered (a little).

It was the same with 16.04 + 16.10 Then I made a new installation 17.04 with /home intact. Some programs were "remembered"

The  "dmesg" command does not inform any failures, but ..... ???

In the startup proc. there always comes a bugreport report concerning 'compiz', but this is never changed !!!

During the initial booting I have approx. 1 screenpage of commands, which I never had before  (16.10 + 17.04) It is not concerning any failure, as I see it.

Comment: You say you kept `/home` when upgrading, so what happens if you create a new user, does that user see the same compiz errors? Since compiz has to do with the display, I would try upgrading the drivers or installing proprietary drivers if available and see if it makes a difference too.

Comment: Do you have an encrypted swap? Do you have an Intel Bay Trail processor?

Comment: Can you provide hardware information ??